# Digitalocean basic droplet for wordpress website showing database error every now and then

Tags: sql, linux, database, wordpress

I have created a basic 5$ droplet with digital ocean to host a wordpress website. After installing the wordpress as soon a i login to the dashboard and start working on elementor or wordpress every few minutes after is shows database connection error which resolves itself after 2-3 minutes and again after 4-5 minutes the cycle repeats. At the same time cpu usagae also increases by 95-99% which drops drown by iteself. As new to server side i dont know whether we have to make some servers changes or some memory changes because as far as I know we can easily host 5-6 basic wordpress websites with medium traffic on a 25GB basic VPS plan. I my case I have not even created a single one. Please help and resolve. Thanks

Comment: is it the single processor, 1GB ram droplet?

Comment: A server provisioned that small doesn't have quite enough RAM for both MySQL and the web server. It sounds like things start to thrash, then the mysqld server calls it quits and restarts.  It maybe possible to tune things so they mostly work, depending on your site's workload. https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Later versions of MariaDB than the 10.3 on Focal Fossa's Ubuntu 20) repo have some auto configuration improvements. Might be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

You should check if:

- server is swapping
- install performance monitoring, digital ocean has it's own script, but you can also install netdata or something more robust
- iostat, I think those net disks are rate limited